# jquery ajax GET query aborted immediately after firing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML button on a page that triggers the download of a zip file from the server. The server code works fine from a browser. The current JS code implements an AJAX GET request in synchronous mode and this works ok. The success callback calls a download function that processes the response and finalises the operation, all this works fine.

Now here is my problem: In this setup I was unable to add a progress spinner (or show a please wait message) while the server comes back with the zip file as nothing would be executed before the ajax request until I made it asynchronous by commenting these lines in the function. Only then I can see my please wait message but now the request gets fired, only to return immediately executing the error callback. TextStatus is "error", errorThrown is "". What is most strange is that the request actually fired and the server processes it but when it tries to write to the response, it throws a 'broken pipe' exception with a nested 'IllegalStateException: Response already committed'.

I have another function that uses a similar pattern but instead of download a file it uploads a file. This one runs ok in asynchronous mode while showing my please wait message. They talk to the same servlet. Does anyone know what may I be doing wrong? Thanks beforehand.

This is my HTML button that calls the JS function:

```
<button id="exportButton" title="Export Project" onclick="exportProject()">Export project</button>
```

The following is the JS function that executes the AJAX request:

```
function exportProject() {
    $.blockUI();
//  $.ajaxSetup({'async':false});
    $.ajax({
          url: 'url/that/works/ok/anywhere/else',
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: 'text/plain',
          headers: { 'operation': 'export', 'Accept': 'text/plain' },
          success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              downloadProject(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('FileName'), data, 'application/zip');
          },
          error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Sorry, there was an error. " + errorThrown);
          },
          complete: function(){
              $.unblockUI();
          }
    });
//  $.ajaxSetup({'async':true});
    return false;
}
```

Finally this is a snippet of the Java servlet that processes the GET request:

```
//Read bytes from file contents
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(zipFile.toPath());

//Encoding bytes to a Base64 string for safe transport
String encodedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);

//Setting response headers for correct browser handling
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setContentLength(encodedString.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='"+zipFile.getName()+"';");
response.setHeader("FileName", zipFile.getName());
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

//Writing ZIP file to response
response.getOutputStream().print(encodedString);
```

Exception snippets from the server (WildFly 10):

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
...
13:11:33,800 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /url/that/works/ok/anywhere/else: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010019: Response already commited
```

Comment: If you want Message to be shown while server is processing. Try this  $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" });    reference: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog

Comment: I'm using the default text for blockUI but nevertheless, the message shows up, the problem is that ajax return in failure soon after firing the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons submit. You are returning false in the function, but the event handler is not.

```
<button id="exportButton" title="Export Project" onclick="return exportProject()">Export project</button>
                                                          ^^^^^^^
```

Other option is to add `type="button"`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I actually added the 'return false' to the JS function following the clues of someone else when searching for answers. I honestly still don't know the underlying cause of the issue but your advice definitely fixed it! Thank you very much. You have saved my day.